# Contribution page in test-drive mode

Tags: contribution-page

I have checked the box that says "contribution page is active" and it's enabled, but end users are still seeing the message that the page is running in test-drive mode!  How do I fix this?

Page in question: https://www.autismontario.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=21

I tried unchecking the active box, saving, then re-checking it, saving.  On my mobile the test-drive mode seems to be gone, but on my laptop (even after clearing cache) the test-drive mode is still showing,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you've provided above works fine: it isn't in test-drive mode). Test-drive mode isn't a setting so that the contribution page only allows test contributions, it's just a slightly different link to access the page, so that you can test drive it (`&action=preview` is added to the URL). The same page can be used in test drive mode and normal mode at the same time, depending on the URL you use to access it.

So, the link that end users are using must be a test drive mode URL. If you can change that link, just use the live page URL for the contribution page. If you can't change the link (e.g. if you sent it out in a mailing), you might be able to set up a temporary redirect in your CMS from the test drive mode URL to the live page URL.